# H1 within DIV not responding to ActionListener which is set for DIV - pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

So basicily what I am trying to do is to set ActionListener for whole div that I'm generating after some user action. Inside of that div I have an h1 marker and some text. When I click on the h1 the ActionListener is not responding. If I click anywhere else inside of div everything is working properly. I am setting ActionListener for parent div with id "list".

```
  document.getElementById("list").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if ( event.target.className === 'note') {
            var id = event.target.id.slice(-1);
            document.getElementById("title").value = titles[id];
            document.getElementById("typedtext").value = notes[id];
        }
   });
```

this is how I generate the DIV:

```
    const divNote = document.createElement("div");

    const h1 = document.createElement("H1");
    h1.setAttribute("id", "h" + number_of_notes);
    const titleNode = document.createTextNode(title);
    h1.appendChild(titleNode);

    const textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
    divNote.classList.add("note");
    divNote.setAttribute("id", "n" + number_of_notes);
    divNote.appendChild(h1);
    divNote.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(divNote);
```

How to make the whole div to be sensitive to ActionListener?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't update the html with `innerHTML`, but rather append a div to your parent with [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Here's what it would look like:

```js
const myElement = document.createElement("div");
myElement.classList.add("note");
/* Other stuff to create the div... */
document.getElementById("list").appendChild(myElement)
```

The problem with modifying the innerHTML is that this will overwrite any previous DOM and all of your eventListeners will be detached.

cf: [addEventListener gone after appending innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2684956/addeventlistener-gone-after-appending-innerhtml)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did what you suggested, but the problem is still the same. When I'm clicking on h1 the ActionListener is not activating.